System spell checker
Is there some kind of system spell checker on ubuntu. That is, any time I type text from the keyboard, the text is checked by a single system utility, not a separate one for each software.
If there is such a utility, how to activate it.

ispell is a command line package available. My personal system installation notes indicate it isn't in the basic .iso from which the Ubuntu system is first installed so it would require sudo apt install ispell

Thank you. So ispell should check spelling in, say, telegram and any keyboard input, as I asked?

It doesn't check in real time.  You run ispell from the command line passing it the file you want checked.  Example:  ispell xyz.txt
